# summation implement in c programming output incorrect

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point

I have to find out the sum of the given series in C programming language.

[image]

As per the formula if n=1 then the output should be 4(2/3)= 8/3

The c programming code that I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i;
    float sum = 0;
    printf("Enter the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum = sum + 4 * ((-1) ^ i / ((2 * i) + 1));
    }

    printf("Sum of the series: %f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the output -8.

What I did wrong in my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` operator in C is exclusive-or, not exponentiation.  There is no exponentiation operator, but you could think about how to get the effect of `(-1)^i` with other operators, such as `?:`.  (You may see advice to use the `pow` function, but it's for floating point, not integers, and so is not a good drop-in.)

The other problem is that dividing two integers does integer division, which truncates any fractional part.  You'll need to cast either the numerator or denominator to `float` or `double` before dividing.  (Generally `double` is a better choice than `float`, except if you have a large array whose memory usage is significant.)

Comment: Thanks I have solved the problem with math.h header file and adding -lm linker flag at the compilation time.